# android not receiving messages from rabbitmq server with messages pushed from ruby-amqp

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabbitmq, amqp

i am using rails with ruby-amqp gem. its working fine with rails app itself but android java client cant able to receive messages.

the android client is based on this 
http://simonwdixon.wordpress.com/2011/06/03/getting-started-with-rabbitmq-on-android-part-1/

```
mConsumer = new MessageConsumer("192.168.1.123", "nodes.metadata", "fanout");
```

my ruby implementation is based on this

```
EventMachine.next_tick do
  connection = AMQP.connect(:host => '127.0.0.1')
  channel  = AMQP::Channel.new(connection)
  exchange = channel.fanout("nodes.metadata")

  channel.queue("joe", :auto_delete => true).bind(exchange).subscribe do |payload|
    puts "#{payload} => joe"
  end

  channel.queue("aaron", :auto_delete => true).bind(exchange).subscribe do |payload|
    puts "#{payload} => aaron"
  end

  channel.queue("bob", :auto_delete => true).bind(exchange).subscribe do |payload|
    puts "#{payload} => bob"
  end

  exchange.publish("BOS")

  # disconnect & exit after 2 seconds
  EventMachine.add_timer(2) do
    exchange.delete

    # connection.close { EventMachine.stop }
  end
end
```

when i run this it works fine i get the publish messages in terminal but
when android is listening to rabbitmq i am not getting messges in terminal and also android not receiving message. i connected rabbitmq in android with ip address of my computer

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with this

mModel.exchangeDeclare(mExchange, MyExchangeType, true);

changed it to

mModel.exchangeDeclare(mExchange, MyExchangeType) (not a passive exchange);
ref https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-discuss/hCtGUefIcRg

and then removed exchange.delete from ruby code (as exchange is deleted you will receive only one message)